# How do I apply conditional statemtents to create a new raster layer based on 3 geospatial files (raster and shape) using R

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements, raster, spatial

I have to assign benchmarks for soil organic carbon values based on three informations:

1. **Land use type**: cropland or grassland? (this information is provided in a shape file, where the fields are given as polygons). Not the entire study area is cropland or grassland, and I only want to apply the calculations to the polygons where this condition is met.
2. **Soil texture** (this info is both available as raster (100mx100m) grid or as shape file. I thought it is easier for the calculations if I use it in raster format)
3. **Carbon value** (raster file in 100x100m resolution)

I am not experienced with spatial data calculations, and with data tables I would just create a nested for loop with all my conditions. However, I don't know how to do this creating a new raster file and 'accessing' the information of both the shape file (land use type) AND soil texture and carbon value rasters.

All files have the same coordinate system and are overlapping.

To make it short, for a similar task I have used somewhat this type of loop with conditional statements:

```
for(i in nrow(new_raster)){
 if(landuse_shp[i] == 'AL'){
   if(texture_tif [i] == 'light'){
     if(carbon_tif[i] >= 0.68 && carbon_tif[i] <= 1.23){
       new_raster[i] <- "1"
     }
    else if(carbon_tif[i] > 1.23){
        new_raster[i] <- "2" 
     }
#and so on... 
    }
    if(texture_tif[i] == 'middle I'){
       if(carbon_tif[i] < 2.4) {
         new_raster[i] <- "0"
        }
    else if(...)
```

This is rather a conceptual question, because I do not have any code yet, as I don't know which first steps would make most sense...
Thanks a lot for you help &cheers

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example. As you suggested it might be easiest to rasterize the vector (shapefile data) first if you're satisfied with the 100 m resolution.

- create some sample data:

```
library(terra)
library(sf) ## only needed here to create sample landuse polygon


## create a sample vector
## or simply: terra::vect('path/to/your/shapefile.shp')
v_landuse <- 
  st_point(c(0, 0)) |> 
  st_buffer(5) |>
  st_sfc() |>
  vect() ## convert to terra-compatible class "SpatVector"


## create sample rasters of random values:
set.seed(42)
raster_height <- raster_width <- 6

## rasterize v_landuse and recode with 'crop' and 'grass'
r_landuse <- rasterize(v_landuse, rast(matrix(1, raster_height, raster_width))) |>
    setValues(ifelse(values(r_landuse), 'crop', 'grass'))

r_texture <- c('low', 'middle', 'high')[1 + rbinom(raster_length ^ 2, 2, 1/3)] |>
  matrix(raster_height) |> rast()

r_carbon <- runif(raster_height^2, 1, 4) |>
  matrix(raster_height) |> rast()
```

run your raster algebra, e. g. identify cropland cells with middle texture and at least 2 units of carbon:

```
r_combined <- all(r_landuse == 'crop',
                  r_texture == 'middle',
                  r_carbon >= 2
                  )
```

inspect the result:

```
par(mfrow = c(2, 2))
ls(pattern = '^r_.*') |> 
    Map(f = \(n) {
        plot(get(n), main = n)
        if(n == 'r_landuse') plot(v_landuse, add = TRUE)
   })
```

[image: combination of rasters]

Comment: thanks, this was already very helpful to get a general idea. I tried to run your raster algebra, but I get the error message [sds] extents do not match (). It is possible that not all raster cells overlap exactly, due to the conversion of the texture and landuse layers from shape files...

Comment: Could be a few reasons ( https://www.google.com/search?q=R+terra+match+raster+extents ). Note that you can also use a single existing "master" raster layer (e. g. carbon?) as a joint rasterizing template: `rasterize(vect(your_shapefile.shp), your_carbon_raster)`.